# editing WordPress related code in visual studio code with proper intelisense

Tags: php, wordpress, intellisense, php-intelephense

There are so many extentions that are supposed to provide intelisense when developing for php in VSC.
can someone please tell me what do i need to do so that I will be able to write code ( used as snippets on a wordpress site ) and have problems detected and proper color syntax?

I tried setting up php inteliphense and use wordpress-stubs from https://github.com/php-stubs/wordpress-stubs but it seems like php inteliphense has opinions about this wordpress-stubs file and says that it hase tons of errors reading `'wp_get_link_cats': not all code paths return a value` on many many functions..

also a line that looks like this:

```
$new_post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
```

results in a "problem" in the ide saying:

```
Assigning "void" from a function wp_insert_post()
```

Is there no way other than adding the actual Wordpress codebase to my project?

Comment: Personally I use Without issues "IntelliCode" + "PHP Intelephense" + "Modern WordPress Developer Snippets" by ryanwelcher + "WordPress Gutenberg Snippets" by Benjamin Zekavica + "WordPress Hooks IntelliSense" by johnbillion … and some few others for WooCommerce and ACF…